# Colinearity in hypothesis testing.

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

My lecture notes write the following about colinearity and I don't know why it's true:

If we reject the null hypothesis for an F-Test and fail to reject the null hypothesis for the T-test while also consequently having high $R^2$ (coefficient of determination), it signals we might have a colinearity problem.